# Can i have multiple implemantions in cpp files with one header and one interface?

Tags: c++

i want to define different implemantions to method say "execute" and run those from main file .
how can i make 1 interface for example :

```
#ifndef _ITESTER_
#define _ITESTER_


class ITester
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~ITester() {};
};



#endif
```

and the co responcing header file :

```
#ifndef _REVERSETEXT_
#define  _REVERSETEXT_

#include "ITester.h"

class General : public ITester
{
public:
    General() {};
    virtual void execute();
};



#endif
```

and thos 2 implemantions in c++

```
#include "General.h"

#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"

void ReverseText::execute()
{
    std::string str = "meir";
    for (int i = str.size()-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        printf("%c", str.at(i));
    }
}
```

and this second c++ file:

```
#include "General.h"

#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"

void FizzBazz::execute()
{
     //fizzbazz
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        bool fizz = (i % 3) == 0;
        bool bazz = (i % 5) == 0;
        if (fizz && bazz)
        {
            printf("%d FizzBazz\n", i);
        }
        else if (fizz) {
            printf("%d Fizz\n",i);
        } 
        else if (bazz) {
            printf("%d Bazz\n",i);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d \n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is i dont know how to define and call each c++ implemantion 
in the main() function . 
i dont want to create more headers files

i want to be able to do somthing like this

```
ITester t1 = new FizzBazz();
t1.execute();
ITester t2 = new ReverseText();
t2.execute();
```

with no more header or class definitions or as short as posible

Comment: `#define _ITESTER_` That identifier is reserved to the implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of your program will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: The code you presented is missing `FizzBazz` class definition and should just work. Is something not working? Did you try it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You can have multiple child-classes inheriting from the base `ITester` class, and each child-class can have its own implementation of the `execute` function (and as `ITester::execute` is abstract, each child-class *must* implement it).

Comment: What you have should work.  Do `ReverseText` and `FizzBazz` inherit from `ITester`?

Comment: `ITester t1 = new FizzBazz();` should be `ITester *t1 = new FizzBazz();`, which then would change the `.` in the next line to `->`, like so `t1->execute();`

Comment: You might have a *factory* if you want to reduce `#include` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: factory will fource  me to create header files

Comment: @Some programmer dude still not good as the class definition is in the cpp class

Answer (score 0):

You must create a separate class for each implementation. They can all be defined in the same header file if you want.

```
class ITester
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~ITester() {}
};

class ReverseText : public ITester
{
public:
    ReverseText() {}
    virtual void execute();
};

class FizzBazz : public ITester
{
public:
    FizzBazz() {}
    virtual void execute();
};
```

Called like this:

```
ITester* t1 = new FizzBazz();
t1->execute();
ITester* t2 = new ReverseText();
t2->execute();

delete t1;
delete t2;
```

Comment: i dont want to create the class, mybe i should use #if #def for the implemention